# How do I store a bash command as string for multiple substitutions?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to clean up this script I have and this piece of code is annoying me because I know it can be more DRY:

```
if  grep --version | grep "GNU" > /dev/null  ;
then
    grep -P -r -l "\x0d" $dir | grep "${fileRegex}"
else
    grep -r -l "\x0d" $dir | grep "{$fileRegex}"
fi
```

My thoughts are to somehow conditionally set a string variable to either "grep -P" or "egrep" and then in a single line do something like:

```
$(cmdString) -r -l "\x0d" $dir | grep "${fileRegex}"
```

Or something like that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you mean to use curly braces as in ${cmdString}.  It should work.

Comment: Or could you give more detail about "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @bmb Is likely correct. That snippet will likely work with curly braces instead of parentheses but that's beside the point which is that this isn't how this should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you worried about a host which has `GNU grep` but not `egrep`? Do such hosts exist?

If not why not just always use `egrep`? (Though `-P` and `egrep` are not the same thing.)

That being said you don't use strings for this (see [BashFAQ#50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

You use arrays: `grepcmd=(egrep)` or `grepcmd=(grep -P)` and then `"${grepcmd[@]}" ...`.

You can also avoid needing perl mode entirely if you use `$'\r'` or similar (assuming your shell understands that quoting method).

Comment: The issue I'm facing is the deltas between BSD/OSX grep and GNU grep in Linux.  In OSX, grep assumes -P by default but in Linux/GNU grep, I have to proactively specify it.  It's arbitrary that I chose egrep on OSX, I will update the original post to remove that from consideration.

Comment: @jshort A quick look at the OS X grep man page doesn't indicate a -P flag at all (which is presumably the issue) but it also does not indicate that it defaults to Perl regex mode. Though that might just be a shortcoming of the man page I suppose.

Comment: That is exactly correct.  To grep for control M characters like I am above, it needs to be in perl regex mode which in Linux I get via the -P flag.  However, in OSX it works without the -P flag (which doesn't exist and grep fails if you pass it).

Comment: I see the edit and that worked, and fortunately/unfortunately undoes the need for this kind of logic! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if  grep --version | grep "GNU" > /dev/null
then
    cmdString=(grep -P)
else
    cmdString=(egrep)
fi

"${cmdString[@]}" -r -l "\x0d" "$dir" | grep "{$fileRegex}"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Etan Reisner's suggestion worked well.  For those that are interested in the final code (this case is for tabs, not windows line endings but it is similar):

```
fileRegex=${1:-".*\.java"}

if grep --version | grep "GNU" > /dev/null ;
then
   cmdString=(grep -P)
else
   cmdString=(grep)
fi

arr=$("${cmdString[@]}" -r -l "\x09" . | grep "${fileRegex}")

if [ -n "$dryRun" ]; then
    for i in $arr; do echo "$i"; done
else
    for i in $arr; do expand -t 7 "$i" > /tmp/e && mv /tmp/e "$i"; done
fi
```

Comment: This is going to fail if any of your returned lines contain shell wildcard characters as the variable expansion in the for loop will be subject to filename expansion and globbing. Among other possible issues.

Comment: I've been using this script (disregarding the topic to clean up the duplicate code) for a long time and never had a problem.  What is a case that would cause it to fail?

Comment: Create a `*.java` file in that directory with a tab in it. Or take an existing java file (which gets included in your list) and replace one character with a literal question mark.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for a more in-depth discussion of the underlying issue.